# Build a whoosh scoring implementation that looks at how 'near' different terms are

Tags: python, whoosh

I need my score to take into account only how close the terms (in a multi-term search) are. It looks like in implementing your own weighting function ([the docs](http://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/api/scoring.html#module-whoosh.scoring)), you only get access to one term of the search at once, so cannot look at distance between two terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found is to index each sentence alone. This isn't ideal, since it'll allow no highly scored exceptions to come through.